# Is it possible to listen for keydown and keyup while resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events, window-resize

I'm trying to detect `keydown` and `keyup`, while the window is being resized. What I've tried so far, only fires the key events *after* the resize is finished.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log("resizing");    
});

$(window).keydown(function(e){
    $("#key").css("background","green");
});

$(window).keyup(function(e){
    $("#key").css("background","red");
});
```

Comment: Seems to work for me (in Chrome) - http://jsfiddle.net/B5mfs/

Comment: Hm. Why do you need to type something while resizing?

Comment: @bfavaretto - at the same time it does not work in IE9. Suppose that depends on how browser pass events to JS and could not be changed.

Comment: @FAngel I don't need to type anything, I just need to listen for keydown/up while resizing

Comment: @bfavaretto in Chrome (and Canary) on Mac, it doesn't fire until you're done resizing.

Comment: Weird, it does work for me on Chrome 21 OSX 10.7.5 if I first focus on the output iframe (on jsfiddle), then resize. I can see keyup/keydown being fired if I type while resizing.

Comment: Such question just  confuse me. I can hardly immagine someone typing on keyboard while resizing a window with a mose. But anyway - my point is that if browser does not fire such events - you can do nothing with that.

Comment: @FAngel You can see here what I'm trying to do: https://github.com/lassse/resize-accordion

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so part of the problem you may be running into here is that keydown isn't an `on` or `off` thing, it's a fire-constantly thing.
The same is true of `onresize`.

As you resize the window the event gets called over and over.
Also, because JS isn't multithreaded, only one of these events is going to happen at one time.
The other event is going to be queued up to run immediately after the other event finishes.

So what you actually want is a state machine that one event sets, and the other event checks.

Quick examples:

```
var BrowserWindow = { width : 0, height : 0, prevWidth : 0, prevHeight : 0 };

window.onresize = function (e) {
   /* set prevWidth/prevHeight, get new width/height */
};

window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (BrowserWindow.prevWidth !== BrowserWindow.width) { /*...*/ }
};
```

That would work (except that it would only work when the screen was actively being stretched... so it wouldn't happen in the case where the key was down and the edge of the window was being held but not dragged (which might lead to flickering if the browser fires keydown events more-frequently than resize).

The more appropriate answer would likely be to go the other way:

```
var Keyboard = {
    currentKeys : {},
    previousKeys : {}
};


window.onkeydown = function (e) { Keyboard.currentKeys[e.keyCode] = true; };
window.onkeyup   = function (e) { delete Keyboard.currentKeys[e.keyCode]; };


window.onresize = function (e) {
    var key = <X>,
        state = "";

    state = Keyboard.currentKeys[key] && !Keyboard.previousKeys[key]
          ?    "pressed"
          : !Keyboard.currentKeys[key] && Keyboard.previousKeys[key]
          ?    "released"
          : Keyboard.currentKeys[key] && Keyboard.previousKeys[key]
          ?    "held"
          :    "off";

    Keyboard.previousKeys = Keyboard.currentKeys;
    doSomething(state);
};
```

This is less than perfect from an architecture standpoint, but is more along the idea of what you'd have to do in another environment.